# Why is the number of bee routes between $5$ flowers not equal to $5!$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

On a BBC program about algorithms, they talked about solving the travelling salesman problem. They used the analogy of a bee hive with five flowers to visit before returning to the hive? They said that there were 60 possible routes. Am I missing something or should it not be 5! = 120?

Comment: Could you give us a link?

Comment: My guess: If you go backwards along a route it has the same cost as going forward, hence the factor of two.  But without context that's just a guess.

Comment: May be the first flower is decided from the beginning, may be details are missing...

Comment: This article may be related:http://www.science20.com/news_articles/how_bumblebees_solve_traveling_salesman_problem-94714

Comment: Nate, you've got it. Out of the 120 possible routes, half of them are identical just in reverse order. So the time taken to complete them would be the same. Thanks

Comment: @Jack: So for visiting 2 flowers from the beehive, according to you there is only **one** route !

Comment: As any bee knows, a given route generally takes longer to fly around in one direction than the reverse direction, because the wind is not constant throughout the route. So there really are 120 routes from the bee's point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You have not missed anything.

Including the beehive, there are $6$ nodes, and the total number of paths for $n$ nodes is given by $(n-1)!$, so it has to be $120$ for this case.

See under "Difficulty" [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Actually, the real difficulty of this type of problem is finding the **shortest** route, and trying out all possible routes becomes prohibitive as $n$ increases.

**PS:**

We have to count number of paths from hive (H) to flowers and back
For 3 flowers, say, [ mind it, $n = 4,$ possible routes are

$H-1-2-3-H,\; H-1-3-2-H,\; H-2-1-3-H,$

$H-2-3-1-H, \;H-3-1-2-H,\; H-3-2-1-H,$

$6$ or $3! = (n-1)!$

**PPS:**

So the number of routes with $5$ flowers = $120$,

but the number of routes **of the same length** (assuming reverse route doesn't change distance ) = $60$

but the question as given here didn't ask that.